# delete and add list in custom listview in android

Tags: android

I had created dynamic layout and that set as list in custom listview using adapter. In that dynamic layout one button , when i click on that button then that layout delete from list  and add new dynamically created layout at deleted position.

I used some way to solve it.but not work it:

```
holder.ll_business_reviews.removeViewAt(v.getId());                                          

holder.ll_business_reviews.addView(ll_fnl,v.getId());                                               

notifyDataSetChanged();
```

(ll_fnl this is a dynamically created layout.

Comment: pls post some code so we can help you

Comment: there are one api that contain some data that save in four class of getter setter .there are one page and four button every button contain one listview that is custom listview. first click call first adapter and ans so on. but problem is in four adapter i fouth adapter i will created dynamic layout . In layout one button .when i click on that button open a custom dialog box and there ate edit box  put data and click on dialog button and that exchange layout with newly created layout in that position. that replacement of layout is not work.

Comment: i get that button id using click event and delete using holder.ll_business_reviews.removeViewAt(v.getId());  and add new layout using holder.ll_business_reviews.addView(ll_fnl,v.getId());                                               
 but not work it.